# HTTP redirecting to HTTPS automatically in ASP.NET MVC - how to avoid it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, https, microsoft-edge

I have inherited an ASP MVC app (Framework), in the solution properties > Web, it is http and not https

[image]

When I hit Debug > IIs Express > Edge , I get redirected to https with erro connection as you can notice hereunder
[image]
I searched everywhere in the app I was not able to find any redirect Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be caused by [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) or [Automatic HTTPS](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2021/06/01/available-for-preview-automatic-https-helps-keep-your-browsing-more-secure/).

- **HSTS:** You can navigate to *edge://net-internals/#hsts* in Edge. Query `localhost` in Query Domain textbox. If there's anything found, delete `localhost` in Delete Domain textbox.
  [image]
  [image]
- **Automatic HTTPS:** Navigate to *edge://settings/privacy* in Edge, scroll down and find **Automatically switch to more secure connections with Automatic HTTPS**. Check if the option is turned on, if it is, **turn off** the option.
  [image]

Comment: So many thanks Yu, I deleted localhost and I was able to access the web site. However, I visited also edge://settings/privacy. I don't have **Automatically switch to more secure connections with Automatic HTTPS.** entry

Comment: @eliassal I think that's because you don't enable Automatic HTTPS in *edge://flags*. You can search **Automatic HTTPS** in *edge://flags* and set the option to **Enabled**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkAd4.png. Restart Edge then you can find the entry in Edge settings. But since you have fixed the issue in HSTS, you don't have to check Automatic HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the fol-up, yes as it was solved following your hint, I did not go further and thanks for the 2nd hint